# Creating an ESRI Shapefile, will it overwrite duplicates? Or rename them?

Tags: gdal, esri

I've created a Program that can create ESRI shape files (this is using Gdal Libaries). While I'm creating the file using a basic for loop to populate some points using a random int. If I add a geometry that has the same name as another geometry. Will it over write that geometry and all its data? or will it create a new one but change its name slightly so it can add it.

Comment: Just try it and see.  It'll depend on Gdal's implementation.

Comment: After a quick test, it just appends a sequential number onto the end of the name, to stop it from duplicating.

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out!  If you want, you can post your own answer, and accept it from yourself for other stackoverflowers.  I think that earns you some points too.

Answer (score 1):

I tested my answer in a basic project which creates a ESRI shapefile, and creates 100 of the same items, with the same name and geometries. It seems to just append a dot then sequential number, so in short it doesn't overwrite a feature, just creates new ones.